# How can I make "rm -rf / " into an alias?

Tags: root, alias, rm

I want to make an alias for `rm -rf /`. I know how to make an alias; the problem is that I don't know how to use a succession of commands to make an alias with all of them. I want something like `rm -rf / = echo 'something'`, but only when "/" is used.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it sounds like you want to make a (probably ill-advised!) function...

Comment: yeah, some of the ppl i work with thought it was a great idea to try that command on my desktop and i want to make sure that this never happens again.

Comment: @Zanna yes it's a terrible thing to run... I think OP goal is to warn against it...

Comment: I'd rather block using rm on / with a password

Comment: Don't know how just now, but what about a wrapper script for rm that checks if the directory is `/`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I just want the output to be different once they try that again.  They are monkey, no idea about how linux works. They just saw that command on a random pic on google and tried it. i was dumb enough to let my pc logged in.

Comment: @CaranfilAlegzandru It seems to me that you missinterpreted the concept of an alias. An alias is an alternative name for a command. It doesn't disable or replace the original command. If I, for example, added the alias `ll` for `ls -l`, *both* `ll` and `ls -l` would have the same effect.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck you are right, but if i added the alias `ll` for `echo "something" ` that would still work, right?

Comment: @CaranfilAlegzandru Then it wouldn't affect `ls -l` (or, in your case, `rm -rf /`) in any way.

Comment: To learn a bit more about alias search the command within '~./.bashrc'. I like the idea of a wrapper that limits it only to subdirectory within users home.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck i know, my point was that it is possible. I just want `rm -rf / ` to `echo "something"` . I know that they can use `cd / && rm -rf * ` but they have no idea how to do that. sure there are lots of ways to work around a simple alias, but they don't know that.

Comment: @CaranfilAlegzandru An alias just isn't a suitable tool in your case. You don't want to *add* another way of doing `rm -rf`, you want to disable or superseed the original one. And that's not what an alias does, it adds another name to a command. heemayl's answer is a more feasible approach.

Comment: I agree that an alias isn't a suitable tool for the OP's goal, but, @HenningKockerbeck, you're harping on an overly narrow interpretation of a technicality. If I alias `ls=date` then, yes, I have defined a new way to learn (and, possibly, set) the system date and time — but I've also disabled the `ls` command from listing files. (And, yes, I know that it's trivial to circumvent, but that's not the point.)

Comment: @CaranfilAlegzandru You don't need to do anything; rm already does this by itself. `# rm -rf /` says `rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’ - rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe`.

Comment: @CaranfilAlegzandru  If your coworkers are entering random commands they found on the internet on any unattended terminals they find, locking down this one command is *not* going to help enough.   You need to 1) always lock your system when you're not there (set the screensaver to autolock after a few minutes of inactivity), and 2) talk to them and explain to them just how badly they screwed up (assuming they wouldn't have done it had they known what it would do) so they're less likely to try something that stupid again.

Comment: This has to be one of the best examples of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 17):

This would be much better done by applying the appropriate permissions to
prevent people from deleting stuff.

This aliasing ‘security’ approach would be easily overridden by disabling the alias, symlinking to `rm` and running it that way, copying the `rm` binary, or possibly even running it directly.

You should secure your desktop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock it when leaving it unattended.

Comment: also scripts that run 'rm' might be confused by the extra output of your alias

Comment: But that would be an issue only if the user runs a script that runs `rm -rf /` (which seems unlikely), and then only if the shell that's running the script expands aliases (which is not default behavior).

Comment: +1 Security through obscurity is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Adding to this answer, this is precisely why Linux allows multiple logins. Create separate logins for your "ppl" -- don't make them administrators! -- or simply enable guest login and let them login as guests. If you do either of these, they can mess themselves up all they like, but they cannot mess up the system or your account.

Answer (score 10):

A simple `bash` function would do (but this can obviously be overwritten by an user):

```
rm () { [[ $1 =~ -(rf|fr) && $2 = / ]] && echo "whatever" || command rm "$@" ;}
```

Note that, even if some user do `rm -rf /`, the operation would not go on as one needs to input `--no-preserve-root` option with `rm` to remove the root directory recursively. (But nothing is preventing one from doing `rm -rf /*` or `cd /; rm -rf *` by the way)

But you should look at implementing a good security policy instead of monkey-patching sensitive stuffs.

Comment: They have 0 experience with linux. They are monkeys, they see a picture on google with "sudo rm -rf / - bla bla" they did it. I wanted just something that can confuse them. and this seems to be a good idea. Thank you !

Comment: Monkey see, monkey do ;)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix exactly! There are some problems where i work and tbh i don't have time to reinstall the os every time a monkey wants to try that again. And a lot of time i forget to lock my laptop when i go for a smoke or whatever. my fear is that these guys will try it again, only next time they will do it on a production server.

Comment: Sounds like a great laptop webcam app to lock the screen when no motion for 1 minute (is you are away from your desk but not just at your filing cabinet in the corner for a minute)

Comment: also , give up smoking ;)

Comment: If you really want to confuse people, install the `sl` command, usually found in the package of the same name

Comment: Or at least give up telling people you smoke ;)

Comment: Why the rollback? Did you read the link I put in the edit description?

Comment: @wjandrea I don't need to, I knew exactly what I was doing. How many times have you see an `echo` failing?

Comment: @heemayl True, but it's a bad example for people reading your code, and if-then statements are easier to read. But anyway, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem here is your system's security. The "ppl" that you work with shouldn't be able to `rm -rf /` since that requires root access - implementing a better security model would avoid incompetent people from breaking the system, plus your `rm` command should (if it's a recent version) implement `--no-preserve-root`.

Comment: As long as the machine is unlocked, anybody can *type* `rm -rf /`. They shouldn't be able to delete the entire filesystem if they don't have root access, but, if it doesn't bail immediately (because `--no-preserve-root` wasn't specified), `rm -rf /` will traverse the directory tree recursively until it reaches the OP's home directory and other files that he is able to delete.

Comment: This. Root should be required to `rm -rf /` and gaining root should require a password. Problem solved. If either root can be gained without password or root is not required, your security is insufficient.